# How to write test script in eclipse for appium using Appcenter & AWS as a device farm?

Tags: eclipse, automated-tests, appium, aws-device-farm, visual-studio-app-center

I have used the followings.
 - Eclipse for IDE
 - Framework Appium
 - Language Java
 - Android SDK
 - Maven for build
 - Appium server
 I have downloaded a sample project from [Sample project](https://github.com/King-of-Spades/AppCenter-Test-Samples/tree/master/Appium) configured all the things but getting error. [error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edZaf.png)
I tried all the above mentioned steps but unable to execute. Can anybody help me out so that I can proceed further with appium.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the project is trying to use appium-adb package and it is not installed.

Can you try running `npm install appium-adb` and then run the tests again?

Please let me know if the same error happens again after install.

Hth
 James